# Single Sign On using Open ID or Identity Server4 in WebForms

Tags: webforms, openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have to implement single sign on existing webforms application.

Before OpenID we were using OWIN OAuth library to have single sign on for external logins such as Facebook or google.

I have found that now OpenID is used for external logins but I also found that Identity Server 4 is also used as middle ware on top of OpenID to generate and verify tokens.

Why one would create a complete token verification system (Identity Server 4) if he can use google and facebook authentication using OpenID?

I want that my webform application should include external logins but I am confused what should I use (Identity Server 4 or OpenID connect)?

If OpenID then please let me know that this [article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/24/protecting-an-asp-net-webforms-app-with-openid-connect-and-azure-ad/) is the right path to get start.

Answer (score 1):

IdentityServer4 is simply an implementation of the OpenID Connect Provider specs (Basic OP, Implicit OP, Hybrid OP, Config OP) that allows you to build your own identity service.

Unless you want to build your own identity provider/secure token service then you do not need to use it. If you just want to consume 3rd party OpenID Connect providers like Google and Facebook then you can implement that using the Azure AD guide you linked to.

Comment: can you please share sample code for google provider using OIDC in asp.net MVC?